# Expo AuthSession: WebBrowser.dismissBrowser is not available on android

Tags: react-native, oauth, expo

Having the error running on android:

> The method or property WebBrowser.dismissBrowser is not available on
>   android, are you sure you've linked all the native dependencies
>   properly?]
>   - node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/construct.js:30:26 in _construct
>   - node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/wrapNativeSuper.js:26:23 in Wrapper
>   - ... 19 more stack frames from framework internals

I can open a browser. Once inside the browser if I quit the browser and went back to the application, the above message show up.

I tried look at WebBrowser from expo documentation

> WebBrowser.openAuthSessionAsync(url, redirectUrl)
>   Opens the url with Safari in a modal on iOS using SFAuthenticationSession. The user will be asked whether to allow the app to authenticate using the given url. Unavailable on Android.

What does the line mean? does that mean android don't work etc.

> The user will be asked whether to allow the app to authenticate using
>   the given url. Unavailable on Android.

Comment: `WebBrowser.openAuthSessionAsync` is dedicated to IOS. You can use `WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync(url)` or `WebBrowser.mayInitWithUrlAsync(url, package)`

Comment: what about the AuthSession

Comment: Now I can see the login on the browser. On iOS is ok where once signed in, the app redirect back to the application. Whereas anddroid, doesn't go back to the application.

Comment: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/auth-session/ <- about AuthSession

Comment: Can you show me the code you used and the error and the screen that occurs with the picture or operation screen?